# Running am start command synchronously

Tags: android, android-activity, adb, activity-manager

When I run,

```
adb shell am start -n  com.android.gallery3d/.app.MovieActivity -d /sdcard/1.mp4
```

the control immediately terminates by printing,

```
Starting: Intent { dat=/sdcard/1.mp4 flg=0x80000 cmp=com.android.gallery3d/.app.MovieActivity }
```

Is there a way, where the control of **am start**  exits only after the complete playback is done ?

Please guide.

Comment: The problem is that the playback happens in another process from the command you are invoking, and there is normally no completion callback.  You could write your own playback app which would somehow signal (put a known message in logcat?) but its not clear that you can do this with the existing one.